# Parsing XML using NSXMLParser in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

can you please help me out for this one,  I tried it out in xcode 6 beta 5 and it is working
fine, Now i updated to the latest version xcode 6 beta 7 and now i got a error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`
Here's my code:

```
var url = NSURL(string: NEWSPAGE)
        let operation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url))
        operation .setCompletionBlockWithSuccess({(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in

        // Start parsing Data


        var parser = NSXMLParser(data:responseObject as NSData)
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()




    }, failure: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in

        NSLog("%@", error)

    })

    operation.start()
```

You're Help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: At what line do you get the error?

Comment: Hi Zisoft, i got an error at line  parser.parse()
parser NSXMLParser * 0x00007f9478d82ad0 0x00007f9478d82ad0
[0] NSXMLParser

Comment: Set breakpoints in the functions of your delegate and step through your code to see where it fails.

Comment: i set the breakpoints for every function but it doesnt exceed in 
parser.parse()
please check this photo https://www.dropbox.com/s/67syepxop3wkvyt/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-08%20at%2010.16.15%20PM.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a clean build after upgrading to beta 7?

Do:

Product->Clean

Product (hold down Alt key)->Clean build directory

Window->Organizer->Delete derived data

After that, run your app again

Comment: Still not working, i tried Objc NSXMLParser then bridge it to Swift working fine but i'm still confused with the error :D, anyway Thanks for your help :D

Comment: got the same issue here with the GM... I guess Apple is trying to kill XML